# Distance check at every nth optimization

Tags: java, python, optimization, distance

This is more of a general programming question even though the code is in Java. Please feel free to answer in any language!

I have a list of objects that I iterate over and I want to check if there's any them that are within a distance threshold. In order to do this I have to re-iterate through the whole list to check the distance of each object. I'm roughly doing this (pseudo code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            continue;
        }

        if (dist(objs[i], objs[j]) < 100) {
            // Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some way to optimize this? I know I can use distance squared to avoid the square root, but I don't find it helping that much. Here's my current distance function:

```
Math.sqrt(((vector.x-this.x)*(vector.x-this.x)) + ((vector.y-this.y)*(vector.y-this.y)));
```

If there's an object on the bottom of the screen and one on top, they clearly aren't near each other so how can they ignore one another?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify this? Your code doesn't actually do what you said you want to do: "Check if there's any [of] them which are within a distance threshold" would imply you would stop as soon as you found a single pair within that distance. Your code actually iterates over all pairs and does something for every pair that is within the threshold, which is slightly different to the way you stated the problem.

Comment: What I meant is to execute an operation if an object is within a distance threshold, but in a less brute force approach. It wouldn't break the loop if one is found, it would keep checking for more objects in that threshold.

Like @DM mentioned, I need to make sure a pair doesn't process multiple times though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider partitioning the objects into cells of size `threshold`x`threshold` (e.g. 100x100 in your example). You can perform this partition in a single pass (i.e. O(n)), and represent it as something like a `Map<Cell, List<Point>>` (where `Point` is the type of your original object).

Now look at each cell in turn, say top left to bottom right, along rows. For each cell, you only need to test each point against points in the same cell or in an immediately adjacent cell (and you don't need to compare across cells that you previously compared, so compare within the cell, and to the cell to the right, and the cells below). In the worst case, you save nothing (and it costs a little to do the partitioning), but if the points are reasonably uniformly distributed, this would on average reduce the number of comparisons.

Comment: I think that's called a bin lattice spatial subdivision or space-partitioning tree. It sounds like a good approach.

Comment: @GreenCell It surely is. It just misses one direction (either "down and left" or "up and right"). You could also partition further like 50x50 and then you'd have to check multiple cells in given directions. In order to find out what cells to check, just compute the minimum distance between their points (this is simple). This is profitable as long as the number of cells stays small compared to the number of points (and the points aren't distributed too badly).

Comment: @maaartinus Oops - it is missing one cell-cell comparison. I fixed that. I will look up the algorithm now I know the name...

Answer (score 2):

One easy way you can optimize this is to limit what values of `j` you check.  There's no need to check the distance between points A and B if you've already checked the distance between points B and A.  This should cut the number of checks in half (and as a side effect you no longer need to check if `i==j`).

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < objects.size(); j++) {

        if (dist(objs[i], objs[j]) < 100) {
            // Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes great idea that should help out

Answer (score 0):

@edit i misunderstood the question. You can't do it faster in pessimistic case, bcs you can have O(n^2) pairs meeting distance requirements

Comment: Sorting might be an idea, but you can't really sort them by distance from each other, since there's both x and y coordinates to worry about.